# Align element center keeping the position absolute

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align an element at center of its parent keeping its `position:absolute` and `display: inline-block'. By this strategy, I am unable to keep it center.

Comment: set `right: 0` and `left: 0` and then add `margin: 0 auto`

Comment: can you post a link? suggesting css for the centred element might not be right without knowing what the parent element is doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you only need `position:absolute` no need of `display:inline-block`

set `left:50%; top:50%` and add `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` for making it `center` `horizontally` or `vertically`